# javascript '=' works as linked object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, operator-keyword, splice

I made a code that removes '-1' in array, but I don't want to modify original one.

following is that one.

```
var original = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1 ];
var temp = original;
for ( var i = ( temp.length - 1 ); i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if ( temp[j] == -1 ) {
    temp.splice( i, 1 );
}
```

---

after script executed.
original is [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] and temp also is [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

both original and temp are modified!

why is it?

Comment: and you probably want to know how to fix that: [Copying array by value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/218196).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there is only *one* array - simply, both variables *name* the *same array*. Just like a person (with nicknames), a single object can have *many* names.

**The `=` (assignment) operator in JavaScript does *not* copy/clone/duplicate the object being assigned.**

The `Array.splice` function *mutates* the array (of which *there is only one*) which, when taken with the above, explains the behavior.

To create a shallow clone of an array, `arr.slice(0)` can be useful.

Comment: thank you for your explain about = operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using only one array.

```
var temp = original;
```

Also to mention that the [equal= operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) does not copy the object.

You can try something like this to achieve what you want:

```
var temp = original.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this

```
var res = original.filter(function(i){ return i != -1;});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var original = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1 ];

var tem = original.filter(function (d) {
    return d !== -1;
});

console.log(original); // [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1] 
console.log(tem); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J37tF/